# Swing; How would I position my components in this format?

Tags: java, swing

So, I would like my items to be positioned in the format below; I'm really not confident with positioning  but would like to learn it a bit more. Here is the code as of yet:

```
package com.bleh.harry;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main 
{
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, windowMenu, helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem fileNew, fileOpen, fileSave, windowTheme, windowLayout, windowProperties, helpWelcome, helpHelp, helpAbout;
    private JTextArea mainTextArea;

    public 

    Main()
    {
        JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8,8));
        JPanel mainTop = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));    
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        windowMenu = new JMenu("Window");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(windowMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();                                           //ADDS CARDS TO CONTAINER
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(layout);
        cards.add(mainCard, "2");

        mainCard.add(mainTop, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pseudo code text editor");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(cards);
        window.setSize(1280, 720);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `"... to be positioned in the format below..."` -- what format?

Comment: Sorry, just realized forgot the photo; it should appear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `BorderLayout`...

[image: BorderLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LayoutTest {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, windowMenu, helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem fileNew, fileOpen, fileSave, windowTheme, windowLayout, windowProperties, helpWelcome, helpHelp, helpAbout;
    private JTextArea mainTextArea;

    public LayoutTest() {
        JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        windowMenu = new JMenu("Window");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(windowMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout(); 
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(layout);
        cards.add(mainCard, "2");

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("One", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Two", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Three", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Four", createPane());

        mainTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);

        mainCard.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainCard.add(new JScrollPane(mainTextArea));

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pseudo code text editor");
        window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(cards);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected JPanel createPane() {

        return new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }

        };

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here, is the amount of space that the `JTabbedPane` wants is depended on it's content...

You could even try using a `GridBagLayout` which might give you a little more control...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LayoutTest {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, windowMenu, helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem fileNew, fileOpen, fileSave, windowTheme, windowLayout, windowProperties, helpWelcome, helpHelp, helpAbout;
    private JTextArea mainTextArea;

    public LayoutTest() {
        JPanel mainCard = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        windowMenu = new JMenu("Window");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(windowMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();                                           //ADDS CARDS TO CONTAINER
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(layout);
        cards.add(mainCard, "2");

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("One", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Two", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Three", createPane());
        tabbedPane.add("Four", createPane());

        mainTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 0.25;
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        mainCard.add(tabbedPane, gbc);
        gbc.weightx = 0.75;
        mainCard.add(new JScrollPane(mainTextArea), gbc);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pseudo code text editor");
        window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(cards);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected JPanel createPane() {

        return new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }

        };

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just remember, the `JMenuBar` belongs to the window ;)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank ever so much, I know I'm not meant to leave comments regarding thanks, but truly you deserve it for the amount of time you dedicated to help me. I'm not going to copy your code as I feel as though i'd be cheating myself so I have read through it and now have a clear understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Play around with, change a few things, add you own components into the fray, see where it takes you.  Neither approaches are better or worse than each other, but you need to supply context in order to decide which will work for you

Comment: It's great! I'm finally getting somewhere; I now have 3 panels from left to right in the middle, I'm ordering components etc, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To lay components out next to each other, I'd recommend using a `BoxLayout`. A `BoxLayout` takes an orientation parameter and lays components out accordingly. The two most used options are `X_AXIS` and `Y_AXIS`. `X_AXIS` lays things out left to right while `Y_AXIS` lays things out top to bottom. You want `X_AXIS`.

To set the layout with a `BoxLayout` using an instance of `JFrame` named `window`, do:

`window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(window, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));`

Comment: I understand what components to use; the layouts are what really confuse me. I just don't understand how to position the components

Comment: Updated with some help for setting a `BoxLayout`.

Comment: You have totally lost me, is there any possibility of you explaining with some extra code please?

Comment: Sure, let me type this out.